# need help solving geometric series questions

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, proof-verification, geometric-series

> A geometric sequence has its first term as $10000$ and a fourth term as $−7290$.
>   If the pattern continues forever, find the sum of the terms in the sequence.

I know that the $n^{th}$ term is found by $$t_n=a_1r^{n-1}$$ where $a_1$ is the first term and $r$ is the common ratio.

Thus the fourth term is given by $$10000 * r^3 = -7290$$

so $$r^3 = -0.729$$ $$r= -0.9$$

So the sum of the series is: $$S_ \infty = \frac{10000}{1-(-0.9)}$$

Is this correct?

2. The sum of the first 2018 terms of a geometric sequence is 200. The sum of
   the first 4036 terms is 380. Find the sum of the first 6054 terms

Comment: No. 1 is correct. For number 2, use $S_n=a \cdot \frac {r^n-1}{r-1}$ for both $S_{2018}$ and $S_{4036}$ and form two equations in terms of $a$ and $r$. You can solve them simultaneously to find $a$ and $4$, therefore finding $S_{6054}$.

Comment: I had to remove the second question from the OP's original post, refer to [this post](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6464/posting-multiple-questions-as-one). But now the removed question has been answered, so @user130306 it would make sense if you edit the post and add the second question back.

Comment: In case the OP does not make the required edit, here is the second question (which has been answered below):  
The sum of the first 2018 terms of a geometric sequence is 200. The sum of the first 4036 terms is 380. Find the sum of the first 6054 terms.

Answer (score 2):

For #1 Yes. You correctly used the formula for the sum of an infinite geometric series. It works because $|-0.9|<1.$

For #2, let's try to write it out.

The first 2018 terms would be $a+ar^1+ar^2...ar^{2017}$

The first 4036 terms would be $a+ar^1...ar^{2017}...ar^{2018}+ar^{2019}..ar^{4035}$

Notice that this is simply $(a+ar^1+ar^2...ar^{2017})(1+r^{2018})$.

You can figure out that $1+r^{2018}=1.9$ because the first $2018$ terms add up to $200$ and the first $4036$ to $380$.

Therefore, $r^{2018} = 0.9$.

Finally, the first 6054 terms, as you may be able to tell, is equal to $(a+ar^1+ar^2...ar^{2017})(1+r^{2018}+r^{4036})=200(1+0.9+0.9^2)=200(2.71)=\boxed{542}$

Answer (score 2):

Your first answer is correct.

For the second, you need to do some sum manipulations. You know if the first term is $a$ and the ratio is $r$, and if we call the known sums $S_1,S_2$,

$$S_1 = \sum_{n=1}^{2018} ar^{n-1} = 200 \;\;\;\;\; S_2 = \sum_{n=1}^{4036} ar^{n-1} = 380$$

Now, we want to find

$$S = \sum_{n=1}^{6054} ar^{n-1}$$

Note that we can split up $S$ as so:

$$S = \sum_{n=1}^{6054} ar^{n-1} = \sum_{n=1}^{4036} ar^{n-1} + \sum_{n=4037}^{6054} ar^{n-1} = S_2 + \sum_{n=4037}^{6054} ar^{n-1}$$

From the latter, notice what happens if we factor out $r^{4036}$ and then reindex the sum with $m=n-4036$:

$$\sum_{n=4037}^{6054} ar^{n-1} = r^{4036} \sum_{n=4037}^{6054} ar^{n-1-4036} = r^{4036} \sum_{m=1}^{2016} ar^{m-1} = r^{4036}S_1$$

Thus,

$$S = S_2 + r^{4036}S_1$$

We still need $r$. We can do similar trickery with $S_2$ though:

$$S_2 = \sum_{n=1}^{4036} ar^{n-1} = 380 = \sum_{n=1}^{2018} ar^{n-1} + r^{2018} \sum_{n=1}^{2018} ar^{n-1} = r^{2018}S_1 + S_1$$

Thus,

$$r^{2018} = \frac{380  - S_1}{S_1} = \frac{380 - 200}{200} = \frac 9 {10} \implies (r^{2018})^2 = r^{4036} = \left(\frac 9 {10} \right)^2 = \frac{81}{100}$$

Then

$$S = S_2 + \frac{81}{100} S_1 = 380 + \frac{81}{100} \cdot 200 = 542$$

Comment: Shouldn't it be $S_1 = \sum_{n=1}^{2018} ar^{n-1} = 200 $?

Comment: Yeah, my bad. I think I made that typo all over the place, I'm used to starting at a "zeroth" term.

Comment: It looked like a mostly copy-and-paste job since I wasn't really using the indices and such a ton in the overall work, but I'm double-checking just to be sure.

Answer (score 1):

For your second question, let $S_n$ be sum of first $nth$ terms and r be the common ratio, then we have
$ S_{2018} = 200$ and $ S_{4036} = 380$
Note that 
$$ S_{4036} = S_{2018} + r^{2018} * S_{2018}$$
$$ 380 = 200 + r^{2018} * 200$$
$$ r^{2018} = 0.9$$

Also note that
$$ S_{6054} = S_{2018} + r^{2018} * S_{2018} + r^{4036} * S_{2018} $$
$$ S_{6054} = 200+ 0.9 * 200+ 0.9^2 * 200 $$
$$ S_{6054} = 542$$

Comment: "For your first question, I think you are asked to find the sum up to nth terms, not the sum till infinite term. I think your answer is not right." -- I disagree. The question explicitly states it continues forever and asks you to find the sum. It is much more likely an infinite sum.

Comment: Oops, didn’t notice the “continue forever”

Comment: thank you! this is a very helpful answer. can you just explain how or why $S_{4036} = S_{2018}+r^{2018}*S_{2018}$ I just don't understand why $r^{2018}$ is multiplied by $S_{2018}$

Comment: Let $a$ be the first term and $r$ be the common ratio, then   $$S_{4036} = (a + ar + ar^2 +......+ar^{2017} )+ (ar^{2018} + ar^{2019} + ...... + ar^{4035} )$$   $$S_{4036}= (a + ar + ar^2 +......+ar^{2017} )+ r^{2018}*(a + ar + ar^2 +......+ar^{2017} ) $$